# Serenity BDD Multi-Module JUnit Screenplay Report Aggregation Problems

Tags: maven, junit, serenity-bdd

I am setting up a *multi-module maven* project to create UI tests for a large browser based application using *junit* and the *screenplay*  bdd pattern.

Each module works and reports as expected individually, however, if I try to run the tests at the top level of the project then - the tests run, but the report *doesn't* include ALL of the child modules.

I get a report with details from only 1 of the modules.

I have created a simple test example as follows;

The "simple" Maven project was created in Eclipse and the module test projects were created with

**mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=screenplay**

and modified the tests to be different on each one.

The pom was updated to use serenity version **2.0.81**

I have the following in the poms at all levels in the project

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${serenity.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>serenity-reports</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>aggregate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Project folder structure is;

```
UITesting
  pom.xml
  serenity.properties
  demo_one
    src
      test
        java
        resources
          uk / co / test / 
            features
              feature_folder_one
                package-info.java
                StoryClassOne.java
            tasks
            ui
    pom.xml
    serenity.properties
  demo_two
    src
      test
        java
        resources
          uk / co / test / 
            features
              feature_folder_two
                package-info.java
                StoryClassTwo.java
            tasks
            ui
    pom.xml
    serenity.properties

and same for demo 3
```

and I set the output directory in the each level serenity.properties file
**serenity.outputDirectory=c:/temp/uireport**

I want the Requirements, Features and Stories tabs to consolidate all of the child module report data.  The actual tests and tags are consolidated, but nothing else is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some feedback on this from serenity core github issues states;

> This won't happen automatically - multi-module tests aren't supported in this way.